# Chrome automatically changing Knowledge font on a page to Times New Roman

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

For some reason my Chrome browser just started incorrectly displaying pages utilizing the 'Knowledge' font, converting them all to Times New Roman. Earlier Chrome had been displaying the fonts correctly and IE still does as well. I've tried another machine with Chrome and it displays the fonts correctly. Any ideas where I should start to troubleshoot this issue? Thanks.

Comment: DId you install a chrome extension recently? Try disabling all extensions and see if that fixes it. Also try to create a new user in chrome and run a 'clean' version of it.

Answer (score 0):

in address bar type:

chrome://settings/

Next:

Click on Advanced Settings: Web Content

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from there. Set my standard font to something else? I'm not really sure that solves the problem of why the fonts start changing to begin with? If I browse to a page with CSS that specifies a certain font family it should display that font family, no?

Comment: It sounds like a local setting since it works on another computer.  But, yes....if the css on that page specifies the font, it should display it.  If local issue:  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416?hl=en